# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `Book`(
 `bookid` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `img` VARCHAR(255) BLOB NOT NULL,
 `stars` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `desc` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = armscii8
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BLOB NOT NULL,
> `stars` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER
> SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode' at line 6

Comment: a column can't be both `VARCHAR(255)` and  `BLOB`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined two data types for this column:

```
 `img` VARCHAR(255) BLOB NOT NULL,
       ^ one        ^ two
```

You must define only one data type for a given column. Pick one of these and remove the other.